# Build failing? Apple Mach-o linker error?

Tags: ios, linker-errors

My app was working fine until I started playing with archiving.  Im not getting any compiler warnings or errors, but when I run the app, the build fails, saying

Apple Mach-o linker error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I commented out all the archiving code I was playing with, but the build continues to fail, and I have no idea why.  Again theres no warning/errors until I build, so  I don't know what happened or where its coming from?

Can anyone tell me what this means and what I need to do to fix it?

EDIT:

Here is what the issue navigator says:

/Users/MikeGordon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HW1ARC-egqtecfuosawiadlwgfulhqjdhtr/Build/Intermediates/HW1ARC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HW1ARC.build/Objects-normal/i386/Assignment.o
ld: 18 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: 18 duplicate symbols for architecture i386

EDIT: Here are some screen shots

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw2CZ.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c53Mm.jpg

http://imgur.com/Ena17FF

Comment: Can you post what you see when you select the error in the issue navigator? Do you see something like "Undefined symbols for architecture..."?

Comment: @singingAtom I added it to the question.  I am assuming thats the part of it you were looking for?

Comment: Select the Project Navigator tab and on the search bar at the bottom type "Assignment". Do you have more than one file with the same name of the same type? e.g. two implementation files named Assignment with extension .m

Comment: @singingAtom No there is only 1 Assignment .m/.h

Comment: I think there should be more than just that in the issue navigator. Can you not post a screenshot of the error description displayed when you select the issue in the issue navigator?

Comment: @singingAtom screenshots added

Comment: Maybe it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45233066/1514066

Answer (score 0):

Check that there are no duplicates under Targets/Compiled sources. If there are duplicates, delete them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but many of my .m/.h files were duplicated and under other folders.  To remedy the problem, I deleted one copy of the file from one of the folders.  The other duplicate file, then turned red.  So, then I deleted the second copy of the file.  At that point, I had no instances of either file in xCode.  Then I went to my Trash, sorted by Date Added, highlighted the files that were just placed in Trash, right clicked and selected Put Back.  The I went to File> Add Files to ("myProject") and selected the files I just restored.  Everything was back to normal at that point. I ran the simulator and it all worked great!

Peculiarly, the Trash only had one instance of the file, even though it was referenced twice in the Project Navigator.